# Convert file with coordinates, keep record ID

Tags: convert, coordinate-system, proj

I have the following sample data:

```
345 -515561.05 -1166540.03
456 -515542.01 -1166548.76
999 -515519.61 -1166552.19
789 -515505.29 -1166550.25
321 -515477.05 -1166546.82
201 -515431.12 -1166534.06
197 -515411.45 -1166517.39
```

First column is id of record and the other two are coordinates. I need to convert coordinates and I'm using `cs2cs` to do this:

```
cs2cs +init=esri:102067 +towgs84=570.8,85.7,462.8,4.998,1.587,5.261,3.56 +to +init=epsg:4326 input.txt
```

However, this works only in the case when file contains only coordinates, no record id. How do I keep record id in output and get something like this:

```
345 17d44'38.14"E 49d13'3.475"N 43.479
456 17d44'39.117"E 49d13'3.251"N 43.479
999 17d44'40.234"E 49d13'3.207"N 43.478
789 17d44'40.93"E 49d13'3.313"N 43.478
321 17d44'42.304"E 49d13'3.508"N 43.478
201 17d44'44.506"E 49d13'4.057"N 43.477
197 17d44'45.398"E 49d13'4.653"N 43.476
```

I think this is needed frequently, but I can't find any example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the field names and value separators in a text editor and save it as CSV file (e.g. input.csv):

```
ID;E_COORD;N_COORD  
345;-515561.05;-1166540.03
456;-515542.01;-1166548.76
999;-515519.61;-1166552.19
789;-515505.29;-1166550.25
321;-515477.05;-1166546.82
201;-515431.12;-1166534.06
197;-515411.45;-1166517.39
```

Then write an OGR VRT file like this (e.g. input.vrt) considering ESRI:102067 in the Proj4 format and adding the +towgs84 parameters as LayerSRS:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="input">
        <SrcDataSource>input.csv</SrcDataSource>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
        <LayerSRS>+proj=krovak +lat_0=49.5 +lon_0=24.83333333333333 +alpha=30.28813975277778 +k=0.9999 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs +towgs84=570.8,85.7,462.8,4.998,1.587,5.261,3.56</LayerSRS>
        <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="E_COORD" y="N_COORD"/>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

Finally, you can do the coordinate transformation using ogr2ogr:

```
ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4326 temp.shp input.vrt
```

add the coordinates thanks to SpatiaLite and convert as CSV file (e.g. output.csv):

```
ogr2ogr -f CSV output.csv temp.shp -dialect SQLite -sql "SELECT *, X(geometry) AS LON, Y(geometry) AS LAT FROM temp"
```

You will obtain this result:

```
ID,E_COORD,N_COORD,LON,LAT
345,-515561.05,-1166540.03,17.7439276860783,49.2176319643844
456,-515542.01,-1166548.76,17.7441990310852,49.2175696464346
999,-515519.61,-1166552.19,17.7445095675043,49.2175575802197
789,-515505.29,-1166550.25,17.7447028376989,49.2175868701976
321,-515477.05,-1166546.82,17.7450844830497,49.2176410870121
201,-515431.12,-1166534.06,17.7456960754081,49.2177935648797
197,-515411.45,-1166517.39,17.7459437617722,49.2179591961173
```

Comment: When running the first ogr2ogr command: `ERROR 6: EPSG PCS/GCS code 5514 not found in EPSG support files.  Is this a valid
EPSG coordinate system?
ERROR 1: Failed to import LayerSRS `EPSG:5514'.` Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @TomasGreif This is the same error I get for ESRI:102067. What version of GDAL (_gdalinfo --formats_) are you using? Mine is GDAL 1.10.0, released 2013/04/24. In order to fix this we can apply the [Proj4 format of ESRI:102067](http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102067/proj4/) adding the +towgs84 parameters in the VRT file.

Comment: @TomasGreif Yes, I can confirm that the workaround works. So I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: OK, I've upgraded and now it works. Your approach is much faster than my bash script, I've just converted 2,900,000 rows in approx. 1 minute.

Answer (score 2):

I've used short bash script to solve this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
filename="$1"
rm -f coord_trans_out.txt
while read -r line
do
    name=$line
    a=( $name )
    coord="${a[1]} ${a[2]}"
    outcoord=$(echo "$coord" | cs2cs -f "%.6f" +init=esri:102067 +towgs84=570.8,85.7,462.8,4.998,1.587,5.261,3.56 +to +init=epsg:4326)
     echo -e "${a[0]}\t$outcoord" >> coord_trans_out.txt
done < "$filename"
```

Given input:

```
1 -515561.05 -1166540.03
2 -515542.01 -1166548.76
3 -515519.61 -1166552.19
4 -515505.29 -1166550.25
5 -515477.05 -1166546.82
6 -515431.12 -1166534.06
7 -515411.45 -1166517.39
```

Output:

```
1 17.743928 49.217632 43.478791
2 17.744199 49.217570 43.478577
3 17.744510 49.217558 43.478266
4 17.744703 49.217587 43.478032
5 17.745084 49.217641 43.477574
6 17.745696 49.217794 43.476767
```